# how to send image via sms in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, sms

I am developing an demo in which I have to send sms via my code along with an image, I tries below code

```
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "some text"); 
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(url));
sendIntent.setType("image/png");
```

couldn't find any solution, can anybody tell me how can I do that? Thanks in advance

Comment: one way that not good is covnerting to bit code and sent it and when you do this .size of sms become very big

Comment: sms are 140 characters of text. you cannot send an image in them.

Comment: then how can I send an image can you please suggest me?

Answer (score 1):

one way is converting image to byte code .but size of it become very big.
so sending image by sms is not optimize.
so you can send some very simple image by sms
and you must make a app that is installed on two phone that you want send and recive sms
you app must be able to converting image to byte code and byte code to image

Comment: user may capture or select an image from gallery so I can't reduce size of image, Is there any way to send it via mms or something else
? and its not necessary that my app must be installed in device to which I am sending image.

Comment: @ rahul No.you question in the last was my question .and i search very much but i dont found any way . and i fond that is not exist way

Answer (score 0):

Resize image to smaller size like 10kb. Then encode to base 64. Send data in portions like 8 times thru sms. Then reassemble data on receiving end end decode base64 to image.

Answer (score 0):

https://f-droid.org/de/packages/click.dummer.imagesms/

Image SMS
Sehr kleine Fotos mittels Langtext-SMS und ohne MMS oder Internet versenden

NOTE: This app is no longer maintained, its repo was archived.

Image SMS uses long text SMS to send a very small picture (NOT MMS or Internet). It uses base64 technique (similar to a email attachment) to transfer data. It is a bare metal App and Open Source on github. If you want to enlarge the features, you have to do it by your own!

I love my privacy. Thus I love apps with only a couple of permissions. Image SMS needs only access on:

```
SMS (read and send)
Camera
```

Image SMS does not use access to:

```
Files
Contacts
Internet
```

This may be strange to you, because you need a phone number and there is no contact selection. .

Answer (score 0):

Just upload the image and create the URL/ Share Link on websites like zippyshare, etc.
And copy the URL and paste in SMS.